# What would be the partial derivative of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ with respect to itself $\frac{\partial \dot x}{\partial x}$ be?

Tags: taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, linear-approximation

For context, I'm trying to linearize the function
$$\dot x^2 \sin x$$ about $a = 0$ using Taylor Series. I can't come up with how to solve the second term, $$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x=a}\ \times (x-a)$$ which is $$\left.\frac{\partial \dot x^2 \sin x}{\partial x}\right|_{x=a} \times (x-a)$$

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So, $x=x(t)$ is a function of $t$, right? And we are derivating $f(t)=x(t)\sin(x(t))$ as a function of $t$, right? Or do you want to derivate $f(x) = x'\sin(x)$ as a function of $x$?

Comment: Yes, $x$ can be written as a function of $t$, hence why $\dot x$ is assumed to not have a trivial solution. I want to know how to do the latter of what you mentioned; derivate $f(x) = \dot x^2 \sin x$ as a function of $x$. i.e.   $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \dot x^2 \sin x}{\partial x}$.

Comment: I'm assuming the most diffculty you are having is in the derivative of $x'$ with respect to $x$. We can use the chain rule and do the following (assuming the necessary smoothness about $x$ and $x'$) $x''=\frac{dx'}{dt}=\frac{dx'}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx'}{dx} x'$ and if $x'\neq 0$ around the point you want to analise, you have your solution

Comment: However, I must point out that for most applications, it would be easier to assume $f$ just as a function of $t$ instead of $x$ and just write $f(t)=x'(t) \sin(x(t))$ and derivate along $t$, giving $f'(t)=x''(t)\sin(x(t))+(x'(t))^2 \cos(x(t))$ by product and chain rule

Comment: I forgot the squares on $x'^2$ but you get the idea